# online math/latex editor/engine?

Tags: math, open-source, editor

Are there are any good open source online math editors? I couldn't find anything searching on Google.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://www.mr.ethz.ch/~majer/formula/formula.php. Just type in a LaTeX math expression and it prints a nice representation.

Answer (score 1):

Great, opensource - 
DragMath

Good - 
http://www.codecogs.com/components/equationeditor/equationeditor.php